# Color palette reference for .Net foreground colors?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, colors, foreground

HI everyone,

Just looking for a website or pdf reference which has a color palette of the .NET (Visual Studio 2008) foreground colors? (E.g. like AliceBlue, AntiqueWhite, Cyan....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a  [link](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Colors/default.aspx)  to one

Answer (score 0):

As the link in the accepted anchor above is dead, try these:

At W3.org: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/keywords

At w3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp The picture below shows the first ones.

[image]